# NSLog on the iPhone device

Tags: iphone

I wanted to test my app on the device, but I dont want now to buy apple licence for 99$.

I read some tutorials on the Internet and installed my app, but I cant debug it.
Xcode says that "Error launching remote program: faileds to get the task for process 731"

App works fine, but I cant debug it.

Maybe break points arent the most important for me. The worst thing is that NSLog() doesnt work when I run app on the device...

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe you could provide a link so we can see what you have done. By the way, when you a surious about developing the app and want to submit it to the AppStore, you have to pay the bill sooner or later. Maybe you could safe youself some trouble and do it right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you can't do this without proper development profile. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Buy an iPhone Developer Licence. 99$/Year aren't this much. If you create one paid app, you'll get more than that back. ;-) 
I know it. I did that myself. ;-)

Comment: I disagree. For many people $99 a year can be quite a bit of money.

Comment: Yes sure it's money. But as I said. For me one paid app was enough to get that money back. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The "Console" tab in the Xcode Organizer or iPhone Configuration Utility will give you device log messages. It gives messages for all apps (not just yours!) but that's not the end of the world, really.

Your app is missing the entitlement `<key>get-task-allow</key><true/>`. You might be able to self-sign it with this to make it work. I'm not sure, since I'm not sure what steps you're following to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of NSLog, write to a log file and then read it.

You can transfer it to your PC/Mac by mailing it from your application or just upload it to your computer with SSH if you have a jailbroken iPhone device.